# text-align: right on a span inside li tag

Tags: html, css, text-align

my structure looks like this:

```
<ul class="grupa-playerow">Blabla
    <li class="player-li">Layout1<span class="player-godziny">15.00-17.00</span></li>
    <li class="player-li">Layout2<span class="player-godziny">17.00-22.00</span></li>
    <li class="player-li">Layout3<span class="player-godziny">22.00-24.00</span></li>
</ul>
```

and here goes the style:

```
.grupa-playerow {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 7px 0 7px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
font-size: 11px;
cursor: pointer;
}


.player-li {
padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}

.player-godziny {
text-align: right !important;
color: #5ACFC9;
}
```

I would like .player-godziny span to align to the right. Why isn't it working?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wL2SF/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
float: right;
```

instead of:

```
text-align: right;
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/CbL4P/)**

*If you notice alignment issues, they are likely resulting from your padding settings*

Answer (score 3):

you need add `float:right;`

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HGCue)

```
<ul class="grupa-playerow">Blabla
    <li class="player-li">Layout1<span class="player-godziny">15.00-17.00</span></li>
    <li class="player-li">Layout2<span class="player-godziny">17.00-22.00</span></li>
    <li class="player-li">Layout3<span class="player-godziny">22.00-24.00</span></li>
</ul>

.grupa-playerow {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 7px 0 7px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
font-size: 11px;
cursor: pointer;
}


.player-li {
padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}

.player-godziny {
text-align: right !important;
color: #5ACFC9;
  float:right;/*ADD*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.player-godziny {
float: right;
color: #5ACFC9;
}
```